# ANgularjs: ng-repeat and nested custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to ng-repeat a custom directive, which has an attribute that should change over the iteration.

This is my html:

```
<div ng-controller="WalletsController as controller">
    <bitcoin-address ng-repeat="bitcoin_label in controller.getWallets()"  bitcoin-label="bitcoin_label"></bitcoin-address>
</div>
```

This is my controller:

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('wallets', [ ]);

app.controller(
        "WalletsController",
        function($scope, $http) {
            this.wallets = [];

            var controller = this;

            this.getWallets = function() {
                return controller.wallets;
            };

            $http.get("wallet_addresses").success(
                    function(data) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            var curWallet = data[i];
                            $scope[curWallet.label] = {
                                label: curWallet.label,
                                address: curWallet.address,
                                balance: curWallet.balance
                            };
                            controller.wallets.push(curWallet.label);
                        }
                    }
            );
        });

app.directive(
        'bitcoinAddress',
        function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: '../../resources/html/bitcoin-address.html',
                scope: {
                    bitcoinLabel: '=',
                }
            };
        }
);
})();
```

And this is my template:

```
<div class="col-md-8 dashboardAddressCell dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{bitcoinLabel.address}}</div>
```

What happens is that the template can not resolve the bitcoinLabel variable. I have tried specifying a constant value and the template works. My conclusion is that I am not correctly specifying the bitcoin_label attribute in the html section.I have also tried using {{bitcoin_address}}, but angularjs complains about that.

I have also tried with the following html code:

```
<div ng-controller="WalletsController as controller">
        <!-- <tr><th>Indirizzo</th><th>Saldo</th><th></th>-->
        <div ng-repeat="bitcoin_label in controller.getWallets()">
            {{bitcoin_label}}
            <bitcoin-address bitcoin-label="bitcoin_label"></bitcoin-address>
        </div> 
        <bitcoin-address  bitcoin-label="ciccio"></bitcoin-address>
    </div>
```

It does not work either, but at least it shows the {{bitcoin_label}} value.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `controller.wallets.push($scope[curWallet.label]);`?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? I think that part should work. In fact, if I include `<bitcoin-address  bitcoin-label="ciccio"></bitcoin-address>` in the html page and `$scope['ciccio'] = {address:'hello'};` in the controller, I can see 'hello'.

Comment: I mean that your code should be `controller.wallets.push($scope[curWallet.label])` not `controller.wallets.push(curWallet.label);`.

Comment: Great it worked! Thank you very much! ... But I did not understand what happened...

Comment: Ok, ok, got it! You helped me both in solving the problem and clearing me a bit more with custom directive. If you post it as an answer, I will mark it. Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems pretty simple. Instead of

```
controller.wallets.push(curWallet.label);
```

you should push corresponding `$scope[curWallet.label]` object:

```
controller.wallets.push($scope[curWallet.label]);
```

Because `curWallet.label` is just a string so in the first case `wallets` ends up as array of stings. However you need `wallets` to be an array of objects, each having `address`, `label`, `balance` properties.

Answer (score 1):

You have some problems with your logic. You're putting wallet *labels* into `.wallets`, then iterating over the labels, and then in your `bitcoinAddress` template you're trying to read `.address` property of *the label string* (not from the object where you saved it). Why not simplify the whole thing to this script:

```
.controller("WalletsController", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.wallets = [];

    $http.get("wallet_addresses").success(function(data) {
        $scope.wallets = data.slice();
   });
})
.directive('bitcoinAddress', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '...',
        scope: {
            wallet: '=',
        }
    };
})
```

this directive template:

```
<div class="..." ...>{{wallet.address}}</div>
```

and this body template:

```
<div ng-controller="WalletsController as controller">
    <bitcoin-address ng-repeat="wallet in wallets" wallet="wallet"></bitcoin-address>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `bitcoinAddress` and `ng-repeat` directives creating scopes on the same element could cause some conflict (isolate scope in the `bitcoinAddress` case).

Try adjusting your html structure slightly:

```
<div ng-controller="WalletsController as controller">
    <div ng-repeat="bitcoin_label in controller.getWallets()">
        <bitcoin-address bitcoin-label="bitcoin_label"></bitcoin-address>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That was my original html code, but it does not work either...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `$scope.wallets` instead of `this.wallets`? Also in your `getWallets` function. After that try

```
<div ng-controller="WalletsController">
  <div ng-repeat="bitcoin_label in wallets">
    <bitcoin-address bitcoin-label="bitcoin_label"></bitcoin-address>
  </div>
</div>
```

But if your `wallets` is an array of `non-object` like array of string or integer, use

```
<div ng-controller="WalletsController">
  <div ng-repeat="bitcoin_label in wallets track by $index">
    <bitcoin-address bitcoin-label="wallets[$index]"></bitcoin-address>
  </div>
</div>
```